# Hibernate error node to be traverse cannot be null

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Hi guys i have a question regarding this annoying error. Below it's my code

```
String updateDefaultBU = "update ClientUserVO  set defaultBUnit = :yes where id = (select      max(cu1.id) from ClientUserVO cu1 where cu1.user.id = :userId and cu1.defaultBUnit = :no)";
updateDefaultBU = " and not exists (select cu2.id from ClientUserVO cu2 where cu2.user.id    = :userId and cu2.defaultBUnit = :yes) ";
Query updateQuery = session.createQuery(updateDefaultBU);
updateQuery.setString("yes", "Y");
updateQuery.setString("no", "N");
updateQuery.setLong("userId", userID);
```

I don't seem to understand where does it find a not that could not be traversed, also this error is very general and it could happen for various reasons, could you tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second assignment of `updateDefaultBU` you are changing the content of the variable completely and not concatenating with the first assignment (as I assume you want to do).

It is possible that you get the error because you run `updateQuery.setString("no", "N")` but the second assignment has no `:no` value in it.

Try changing the second line to `updateDefaultBU.concat(" <your string> ")`

Also have you tried to debug to see exactly where the error is happening?

Comment: I was in a bit of a hurry earlier, yes the concatenation problem is the reason for that error. Thanks.